# Java: JPanel background not scaling

Tags: java, image, components

I am trying to draw an image to a JPanel in java and I have that down, good. My problem now is I am attemping to make it scale to the full size of the window, but it is not doing so. I have tried methods, and they either make the image disappear, or there is no graphical change at all.

The code I am currently working with:

```
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Image img;

    public ImagePanel(String img) {
        this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
    }

    public ImagePanel(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
        Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Full class at: http://pastebin.com/CpcBt2j8

I have tried adding in code such at `img = img.getScaledInstance(440, 440, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)` and that has no effect whatsoever. I have also tried making a new image called `scaledImg` and setting `img`'s `getScaledInstance` value to that, and that completely removes the image from display.

How can I get the image to be scaled to the full size I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically scale an image you use:

```
//g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
```

See [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for a complete implementation along with a tiling feature.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the "simplest" approach would be to do something like...

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    Image scaled = img.getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    g.drawImage(scaled, 0, 0, null);

}
```

This is inefficient, costly and may not produce the desired results

To start with, take a look at [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html)

You could also take a look at [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) for more details about maintaining the aspect ratio of the image and scale to fit vs scale to fill.

I would also buffer the result, so that you are not repeatedly scaling the image within the `paintComponent` method which might be caught often...

**Updated with working example**

This works fine for me...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestImagePane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestImagePane();
    }

    public TestImagePane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    Image img = null;
                    img = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/image"));

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                    frame.add(new ImagePanel(img));
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException | HeadlessException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Image img;
        private Image scaled;

        public ImagePanel(String img) {
            this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
        }

        public ImagePanel(Image img) {
            this.img = img;
        }

        @Override
        public void invalidate() {
            super.invalidate();
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
                scaled = img.getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return img == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(img.getWidth(this), img.getHeight(this));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(scaled, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not producing a result at all, as I said I have tried this. The graphics are completely removed.

Comment: What do you mean by *"The graphics are completely removed"*? Apart from the fact that you weren't calling `super.paintComponent`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put down what I mean. I meant that the image that was drawn was completely removed from view, it just leaves the panels.