# Adding a jpanel over a jlabel background

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I know this question has been asked before but i cant seem to implement any of the other answers to my project.  So i have my paint method in my player class here.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
   //makes player(placeholder for real art)
   super.paintComponent(g);
   g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
   g.fillRect(x,y,50,30);
}
```

Then I have my main class here.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/**
* Write a description of class Main here.
* 
* @author Richard Zins 
* @V01
*/
public class Main extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
     Player p1 = new Player();
     Main m = new Main(p1);


     }

     public Main(Player p1)
     {
      JFrame ar = new JFrame();
      JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Users/rizins/Desktop/PacManTestBackGround.jpg"));
      ar.setTitle("Runner Maze");
      ar.setSize(800,600); 
      ar.add(background);
      ar.setVisible(true);
      ar.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      ar.add(p1);
   }
}
```

Now I cant seem to get my player object to paint over my background any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes...

1. `JPanel` by default is opaque, so you need to change it to be transparent
2. `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, so only one component will be shown at the (default) center position, in this case, the last thing you add.
3. You should call `setVisible` last

Instead, set a layout manager for the `JLabel` and add your player class to it.  Instead of adding the `JLabel` to the frame, you should make the label the `contentPane` for the frame, for example...

```
p1.setOpaque(false);
JFrame ar = new JFrame();
ar.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Users/rizins/Desktop/PacManTestBackGround.jpg"));
ar.setTitle("Runner Maze");
ar.setContentPane(background);
ar.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
ar.add(p1);
ar.pack(); 
ar.setVisible(true);
```

I should point out that using a `JLabel` to display a background image like this could cause you problems, as the `JLabel` only uses the text and icon properties to calculate its preferred size, this could cause some child components to be laid out beyond its visible range.

See [How to set a background picture in JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162398/how-to-set-a-background-picture-in-jpanel/22162430#22162430) for more details and a possible solution

Comment: Yes thank you this cleared up some problems I was having on some other projects too thank you for explaining it the way you did!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the JPanel transparent by setting the opaque to false. e.g:

```
panel.setOpaque(false)
```

Try is if this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JLayeredPane` and add your background at the index 0 (indexed with an `Integer` not an `int`). Then you add another `JPanel` that is not opaque (like in @Bahramdun Adil 's answer) and add your player to that.

This way you can have a background and display your player at the same time.

Comment: Or just apply a layout manager to the `JLabel` and add the (transparent) panel to it