# Can't get the buttons to be on the center right position

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm trying to figure out how to position my buttons in the center right position. I added what Ive done so far and I'll add a drawing of how I want it to be.

I'm trying to understand how to determine the position I want in Swing, can't really understand the advantages of each layout.

My code so far:

```
package Game;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton exit;
    private JButton start_Game;
    private ImageIcon puzzleBackground;
//  private JLabel back_Label;
//  private GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();
    private JPanel menu;

    public MainWindow() 
    {
        super("Welcome");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(450,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        menu = new JPanel();
        menu.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //setResizable(false);

        //===== Background =====
        puzzleBackground = new ImageIcon("MyBackground.jpg");
        setContentPane(new JLabel(puzzleBackground));

        exit = new JButton("Exit");
        menu.add(exit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        exit.addActionListener(this);

        start_Game = new JButton("Start to play");
        menu.add(start_Game, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        start_Game.addActionListener(this);

//      
//      back_Label = new JLabel(puzzleBackground);
//      back_Label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //===== Buttons =====
//      back_Label.add(exit,BorderLayout.CENTER);
//      
//      back_Label.add(start_Game,BorderLayout.EAST);
//      
        add(menu);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MainWindow a = new MainWindow();
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == exit)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            //open start up window.
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: A better way to add a BG image is to use a custom painted `JPanel`. Then set the layout of the panel and add other panels of components to it. Note that here the buttons are not appearing largely **because they are being added to a `JLabel`.**

Answer (score 1):

So, your basic problem boils down the following lines...

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
//...

//===== Background =====
puzzleBackground = new ImageIcon("MyBackground.jpg");
setContentPane(new JLabel(puzzleBackground));
```

Can you tell me what the layout manager in use actually is now?  Wrong.  The layout manager is now `null`, because `JLabel` doesn't actually have a default layout manager.

So, the "simple" answer would be to move the `setLayout` call to below the `setContentPane` call, but this would be a short sighted answer, as `JLabel` calculates it's preferred based on the icon and text properties only, not it's contents of child components.

A better solution would be to do something demonstrated in [How to set a background picture in JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162398/how-to-set-a-background-picture-in-jpanel/22162430#22162430) (see the second example)

This means that if the image is smaller then the required space, the components will disappear off the screen.

I went through and cleaned up the code slightly, only with the intention of getting the layout to work

[image: Simple layout]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton exit;
    private JButton start_Game;
    private JPanel menu;

    public MainWindow() {
        super("Welcome");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        menu = new JPanel();
        menu.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(this);

        start_Game = new JButton("Start to play");
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        start_Game.addActionListener(this);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        menu.add(exit, gbc);
        menu.add(start_Game, gbc);

        // This is just a filler, it can be removed, but it helps prove the point

        add(new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
        });

        add(menu, BorderLayout.EAST);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MainWindow a = new MainWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == exit) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            //open start up window.
        }

    }

}
```

I'd also like to point out that extending directly from `JFrame` is also short sighted, it's locking you into a single use container and you're not actually adding any new functionality to the class.

## Example of better structure...

The following is a simple example of a possibly better structure.  It's missing the concept of a "controller", which controls stuff and "model" which maintains the state information which is used by the UI to display "stuff", but gives a starting point

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            // This is just a filler, it can be removed, but it helps prove the point
            add(new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(200, 200);
                }
            });

            add(new MenuPane(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        }

    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton exit;
        private JButton start_Game;
        private JPanel menu;

        public MenuPane() {
            menu = new JPanel();
            menu.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            ActionHandler actionHandler = new ActionHandler();

            exit = new JButton("Exit");
            exit.addActionListener(actionHandler);

            start_Game = new JButton("Start to play");
            start_Game.addActionListener(actionHandler);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            menu.add(exit, gbc);
            menu.add(start_Game, gbc);
        }

        public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == exit) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    //open start up window.
                    // This should be used to notifiy a controller class
                    // that some new action needs to take place, the controller
                    // is then responsible for making it happen
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to add a BG image is to use a custom painted `JPanel`. Then set the layout of the panel and add other panels or components to it. Note that here the buttons are not appearing largely **because they are being added to a `JLabel`.**

Here is an alternative that works along the same lines, with the red panel being the panel which custom paints the background image and the `menu` panel being set to transparent (look for the `opaque` method).

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private JPanel menu;
    private JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));

    public MainWindow() {
        super("Welcome");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        //setSize(450, 300); // use pack() instead
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8,8,8,8));
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
        contentPane.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(
                new BufferedImage(400,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB))));

        menu = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,10,10));

        menu.add(new JButton("Exit"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        menu.add(new JButton("Start to play"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel menuCenterPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        menuCenterPanel.add(menu);
        add(menuCenterPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // do AFTER pack()
        setMinimumSize(getSize());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MainWindow a = new MainWindow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Doing UI in Java is not advised, but ignoring that.

You get (calculate) the height and width of the screen. Then start drawing buttons depending on that. Drawing a button on screens 50% of pixel value width and 50% of pixel value of height will center the button.

Simply crate buttons with variable location that is calculated from main screen px size and place them where ever you want.

Comment: No, actually, you make use of an appropriate layout managers, which have been designed to provide platform independent algorithms for positioning and sizing the components. *"Doing UI in Java is not advised*"- based on what?

Comment: its an assignment i got in OOP principles course in my university so I do not really have a choice..
Thanks everyone, very helpful !!