# Creating a game interface with java Swing/AWT

Tags: java, swing, awt

I started coding a few weeks ago and I am currently trying to create a Java GUI for a game using Swing and AWT. I have created the code below.

```
public class UI {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel backgroundPanel;
    JLayeredPane buttonPanel;
    JButton play = new JButton("Play!");
    JLabel background;

    public UI() {

        backgroundPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        ImageIcon imgBackground = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/img/connect4_4.png"));
        background = new JLabel("", imgBackground, JLabel.CENTER);
        backgroundPanel.add(background, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        backgroundPanel.add(play, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(backgroundPanel);

        frame.setTitle("Connect 4");
        frame.setSize(450, 450);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

 
}
```

With this code I create a panel with a background image and a play button at the top of the screen. However, what I would like to do is center the play button to the center of the image, and that it doesn't take the full screen size but just a fix size (perhaps 50x50 pixels). How can I do this?

Comment: the first step would be to actually add a button

Comment: Use an appropriate `LayoutManager` in a panel to place objects inside it. Default is `FlowLayout` which is very basic.

Comment: There a number of ways you might do this, one of the better ways would be make a custom component capable of painting an image into itself, independent of any other components, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162398/how-to-set-a-background-picture-in-jpanel/22162430#22162430)

Comment: If you're really interested in doing these kind of things, I might suggest taking a closer look at JavaFX instead

Comment: You might want to read this [Connect 4 explanation](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/connect-four#readme) to see all of the steps involved in creating a game.

Comment: 1) use a GridBagLayout on your background panel. 2) add the button to the background panel. By default the GridBagLayout will center the button.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track by having a JLayeredPane field.  But your code currently isn’t using it.

You’ll want to give that JLayeredPane an [OverlayLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html).  Most other layouts don’t define their behavior when components overlap each other.

Place both the background component and the button in that JLayeredPane, then add only the JLayeredPane to your frame:

```
backgroundPanel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
backgroundPanel.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
play.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
play.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

buttonPanel = new JLayeredPane();
buttonPanel.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(buttonPanel));

buttonPanel.setLayer(backgroundPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
buttonPanel.setLayer(play, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);

buttonPanel.add(backgroundPanel);
buttonPanel.add(play);

// ...

frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel);
```