# Jframe.Jbutton with background

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe, jbutton

i wrote this code but when i launch it i can see my background but not the button on it ? please if someone can help me it could be perfect !

```
package hamza;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class fr {

   public static void main(String[] args){

   JFrame frame = new JFrame("ORDERING FOOD APPLICATION");
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("hamburger.jpg"); 
   frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
   frame.setSize(700, 700);
   frame.setVisible(true);

   try {
      frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("fd12.jpg")))));
   } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: That's because the JButton is also missing from your code.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't make the frame visible until you've finished setting up the UI
2. Prefer `pack` over `setSize`
3. `JLabel` does not have a layout manager by default, so you will need to supply one
4. `JLabel` will NOT calculate it's preferred layout size based on it's child components (it will ignore the layout manager), it only uses the `icon` and `text` properties, so beware of that.

[image: Click me]

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("ORDERING FOOD APPLICATION");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("hamburger.jpg");
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());

try {
    frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("fd12.jpg")))));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
JButton btn = new JButton("Click me");
frame.add(btn);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176008/background-image-for-a-jpanel-not-working/24176183#24176183) for an alternative to using a `JLabel` which may be more flexible

Answer (score 1):

You did't add button on frame, try code below

```
JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
frame.add(button);
```